# Codeigniter - Why creating value for input form make the whole page messed up?

Tags: php, html, forms, codeigniter

I'm trying to create registration form using Codeigniter 3. This problem comes when I try to add value in each input like this:

```
value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>"
```

Here's my view content_register.php:

```
        <form class="usr-input" action="/users" method="post">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Nama Lengkap<span style="padding-left: 90px;">:</span></label>
                <input id="name" name="name" size="40" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>"/>
                <br>
                <label for="username">Username<span style="padding-left: 124px;">:</span></label>
                <input id="username" name="username" size="40" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('username'); ?>"/>
                <br>
                <label for="password">Password<span style="padding-left: 125px;">:</span></label>
                <input id="password" name="password" size="40" type="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>"/>
                <br>
                <label for="email">Email<span style="padding-left: 155px;">:</span></label>
                <input id="email" name="email" size="40" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"/>
                <br>
                <label for="telepon">No. Telepon<span style="padding-left: 111px;">:</span></label>
                <input id="telepon" name="telepon" size="40" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('phone'); ?>"/>
                <br>
                <label for="sex">Jenis Kelamin<span style="padding-left: 96px;">:</span></label>
                <select>
                    <option value="male">Laki-laki</option>
                    <option value="female">Perempuan</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <label for="alamat">Alamat<span style="padding-left: 146px;">:</span></label>
                <textarea id="alamat" name="alamat" rows="5" cols="71" type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('name'); ?>"/></textarea>
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Saya telah membaca dan menerima<a href="register"> Syarat dan Peraturan </a>dari .</input>
            </div>
        </form>
```

And the whole page messed up. It becomes like this:
[image]

Before I add value (which the code like this:)

```
        <form class="usr-input" action="/users" method="post">
            <div>
                <label for="name">Nama Lengkap<span style="padding-left: 90px;">:</span></label>
                <input id="name" name="name" size="40" type="text" />
                <br>
                <label for="username">Username<span style="padding-left: 124px;">:</span></label>
                <input id="username" name="username" size="40" type="text" />
                <br>
                <label for="password">Password<span style="padding-left: 125px;">:</span></label>
                <input id="password" name="password" size="40" type="password" />
                <br>
                <label for="email">Email<span style="padding-left: 155px;">:</span></label>
                <input id="email" name="email" size="40" type="text" />
                <br>
                <label for="telepon">No. Telepon<span style="padding-left: 111px;">:</span></label>
                <input id="telepon" name="telepon" size="40" type="text" />
                <br>
                <label for="sex">Jenis Kelamin<span style="padding-left: 96px;">:</span></label>
                <select>
                    <option value="male">Laki-laki</option>
                    <option value="female">Perempuan</option>
                </select>
                <br>
                <label for="alamat">Alamat<span style="padding-left: 146px;">:</span></label>
                <textarea id="alamat" name="alamat" rows="5" cols="71" type="text" /></textarea>
                <br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> Saya telah membaca dan menerima<a href="register"> Syarat dan Peraturan </a>dari .</input>
            </div>
        </form>
```

It works well. The page should be like this:
[image]

**UPDATE**
Here's the controller:

```
<?php

class page extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // path to simple_html_dom 
    }

    function index() {
        $this->load->view('page_header');
        $this->load->view('content_front');
        $this->load->view('page_footer');
    }


    function login() {
        $this->load->view('page_header');
        $this->load->view('content_login');
        $this->load->view('page_footer');
    }

    function register() {
        $this->load->view('page_header');
        $this->load->view('content_register');
        $this->load->view('page_footer');
    }

}

?>
```

Can you help me what's wrong with this code? Or any information that I miss?
Thank you.

Comment: plz share the controller code.

Comment: `action="/users"` what is this **WRONG URL**

Comment: Thank you @AbdullaNilam. That's actually the problem. Thank you so much

Comment: turn on **display_error**

Comment: @bnrfly please accept the answer below

Comment: @AbdullaNilam right away. 2 mins to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your URL into

```
action="/users"
```

to

```
action="<?php echo base_url()/controller/method?"
```

---

Because `action="/users"` is not a valid URL

Comment: happy to help. Enjoy Coding :)